# Can Everte Statum be used on a non-stationary opponent?

Tags: harry-potter, magic

From the [wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Everte_Statum):

> From Latin everte, meaning "to throw out" and statum, **meaning "stand"**. This implies that it would cause the victim to be thrown **from their standing position**, which most notably coincides with the effect seen in the films.

**So must your opponent be standing still in order for this spell to work?** That seems very impractical, even as a dueling spell.

Comment: Try thinking about it as standing *up* instead of standing *still*...

Comment: Does that imply they could be walking or running?

Comment: This is a movie spell which has been fleshed out with speculation by the wiki so this is only really answerable with further speculation.

Comment: Because the movies (and wikia) are nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's never specified. *Everte Statum* is only used once, on a still opponent, then never again.**

Everte Statum is only used once in all the movies, by Draco in the dueling club on Harry. It's never cast again or even referred to after that. At that time, Harry was staying still, however this doesn't necessarily prove that the spell only works on a stationary opponent.

Everte Statum is never in the books, and neither are any spells using the words "Everte" or "Statum" that could possibly give us a clue. The only two instances of "everte" appearing in the books are as part of the word "reverted".

There's no actual evidence for whether Everte Statum can be used on a moving opponent. Even the Latin etymology isn't much help there. "Everte" means "to throw" and "Statum" means to stand. However, "stand" could either mean "standing *still*" or simply "in an upright position".