# Did J.K. Rowling name the 'movie only' spells?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

Inspired by:

[Can Everte Statum be used on a non-stationary opponent?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164289/can-everte-statum-be-used-on-a-non-stationary-opponent)

[Uses of Brackium Emendo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149445/uses-of-brackium-emendo/149446#149446)

There are at least two spells that are named in the films but not in the books.

**Did J.K. Rowling create/provide the names for these film spells during collaboration with the screenwriter(s)?**

(possible second question implied here is "what spells are named in the films but not the books?")

Comment: it's a minor edit to bump it back up because someone destroyed the front page :)

Comment: I'd ask that second question before someone else does

Answer (score 8):

### She named a few of them, but the rest are just "showbiz"

> **Q:** Did you actually write the information that ended up on the Famous Wizard cards? **For that matter, what about the spells in the films? Did you invent those or did Steve Kloves? And why were new incantations created for the movie in the first place? (Example: "Incendio" to "Lacarnum Inflamari".)** (A Mugglenet/Lexicon question)
>
> **JKR:** *Yes, I wrote the information on the original Famous Wizard cards. As you have noticed, a few of them have now popped up on the ‘Wizard of the Month’ cards on my website desk.*
>
> ***Spells in the films – there I’ve lost track. Steve [Kloves] invented some and I gave him others. Some of the new incantations, such as ‘lacarnum inflamari’ must have sounded more dramatic onscreen – although by the time you’ve managed to say ‘lacarnum inflamari’, you’ve surely lost precious seconds in which the Devil’s Snare might have throttled you. But that’s showbiz.***
>
> <sub>[old jkrowling.com - FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20100205161409/http://www.jkrowling.com:80/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=96)</sub>

Comment: aww - answers the question but also indicates we may never know what is from her and what isn't. This will likely be the accepted answer - will hold out for a bit longer just in case

Comment: @NKCampbell - From what I've understood, JKR has contributed a lot of stuff, but the vast majority of film/videogame things were created by other people and she just gave her stamp of approval to.them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Rowling did exercise some creative control over the films in the beginning, insisting on keeping the British end of the series up, and maintaining approval over merchandise, at one point having to veto a Moaning Myrtle-branded toilet seat. So we cant be sure she did unless someone asks her directly but from this she was definitely heard.