# What spells are named in the Harry Potter films but are not named or used in the books?

Tags: harry-potter, adaptation-comparison

Inspired by:

[Did J.K. Rowling name the 'movie only' spells?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164307/did-j-k-rowling-name-the-movie-only-spells)

[Can Everte Statum be used on a non-stationary opponent?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164289/can-everte-statum-be-used-on-a-non-stationary-opponent)

[Uses of Brackium Emendo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149445/uses-of-brackium-emendo/149446#149446)

There are at least two spells that are named in the films but not in the books.

What spells are in the films that are either named on film but not in the books or not in the books at all?

*Note - unless the spell meets the criteria, not looking for *mere* discrepancies (such as Hermione using bluebell flame in the book but a different spell in the film. This example *would* count however because the spell in the film is *not* in the books)

Comment: There's Lumos Maxima. Apart from that I'm not sure - I try not to watch the movies if I can avoid it!

Answer (score 3):

One example is the spell Hermione uses to set Snape's cloak on fire in *Philosopher's Stone*. It isn't named in the book (she used her bluebell flames with no known incantation) and it stands out because surely if she wants a random fire spell she should use Incendio (presumably named after the film was made) but she says 'Lacarnum Inflamari.'

According to an FAQ on JK Rowling's [website](http://web.archive.org/web/20110806214325/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=96), she commented:

> "Some of the new incantations, such as ‘lacarnum inflamari’ must have sounded more dramatic onscreen – although by the time you’ve managed to say ‘lacarnum inflamari’, you’ve surely lost precious seconds in which the Devil’s Snare might have throttled you. But that’s showbiz."

A list of spells that appear only in films or games but not in the books has been compiled by The Harry Potter Lexicon [here](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/spells-films-games/).

Highlights include:

Alarte Ascendare (Lockhart vs Draco's snake)

Everte Statum (Draco's attack on Harry in the same scene)

Fera Verto (McGonagall, for some mad reason, turning animals into water goblets)

Comment: Could you add that FAQ link?

Comment: Also, I encourage you to use blockquotes (`>`) and inline links (`[text](link)`).

Comment: Arresto Momentum appears in some of Rowling's writings, so it isn't a movie-only spell.

Comment: @ibid - Does it appear by name? I was pretty sure it's incantation was never given?

Comment: @ThruGog - [Pottermore QWC - USA vs Jamaica](http://i.imgur.com/3F1YEWX.png?1)

Comment: @ibid - Good find. Replaced!

Comment: @ThruGog - I think a few of the other ones from that list did eventually make their way into Rowling-canon, but none of the ones you've quoted.

Answer (score 3):

Two spells were used in Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets (film) but find no mention in the book:

1. Cistem Aperio: Used by Riddle 50 years ago. He used it to blast open the box containing Aragog so as to frame Hagrid.
2. Ariana Exumai: Used by Riddle in the aforementioned situation after freeing Aragog. It was also used by Harry when he was engulfed by acromantula in the Forbidden Forest. It basically repels the spiders by creating a blinding flash of white light.

Don't know of others. Haven't read the books or seen the movies in whole two years.